# I can't sign-in on Unity Hub

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I downloaded Unity Hub, but there's a big problem: When I click the button to Sign-In on my account, nothing happens, so I an unable to use it. Anyone knows a solution? Or maybe I just have a bad PC?

I tried to Sign-in, expecting to acess my account, but nothing happened

Comment: Do you use a proxy server, look for log files anything. Basically we only have what youve given us and it amounts to its not working. We have no more info than you do

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but what is a proxy server? Also, no log files, no bug reporters, no nothing. This is all the information I can give cause it's the only information I know lol. But thanks for trying to help, your answer will for sure help me find what my problem is

Answer (score 0):

Set Google Chrome as Default Browser on Default Apps